# InstallShield: source and target directories and files

Tags: installation, installshield, install4j

I've been tasked with taking our existing InstallShield based installer and converting it to Install4j. I've been going through the ism file (XML version) trying to figure out what files are being loaded into the installer MSI and then where these files and directories are installed when the MSI is executed. So far I haven't had any luck, we still have a licensed copy of InstallShield 2009, but I don't know where to even look for something like this and the manual has been less that helpful. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the project up in InstallShield and go to the Files and Folders designer.  This will show you the destination view along with the source locations for all the files.

If it's an MSI based project you can build the MSI and then perform an Administrative Installation to extract the files.  The extracted structure will mimic how it would have been installed.

[Administrative Installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)